# What is the Big O notation of for loops located that are nested through methods?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I'm unsure of what the Big O notation would be for the following code (Algorithm name: Remove Shift):

```
Method(main)
    for i=1 to n 
        if isDuplicate (i)
            remove (i)
        endif
    endfor
return n

Method: isDuplicate (i)
    for j=1 to n
        if A[j] = A[i]
            return true
        endif
    endfor
    return false

Method: remove (i)
// Removes and performs a left-shift.
    for j=n-1 to i
        A[j] = A[j+1]
    endfor
    n = n -1
```

So, I know for the runtime of our first loop in main is `O(n)`. The duplicate method is yielding an `O(n)` for the worst case. To remove, there is remove and performing the left-shifting, so for this purpose obviously, we have to check whole elements making it `O(n)` as well. Would that make the runtime of Remove shift, `O(n)` or `O(n^3)`? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is n^3
in the first loop in main you are visiting all numbers from 1 to n this is O(n)
inside it the if condition have function  isDuplicate (i) it is also take O(n) now we have O(n^2) inside the if we have function remove it takes O(n) for every element
now we have O(n^3) in the worst case and O(n^2) if the function isDuplicate (i) return false....

Comment: The math you have here doesn't give an upper bound of O(n^3). That would assume you multiply together the three runtimes, though two of them get added together.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find it helpful to differentiate between two concepts:

1. How many times does a loop run?
2. How much work does a loop do?

For example, let's take this first loop:

```
Method(main)
    for i=1 to n 
        if isDuplicate (i)
            remove (i)
        endif
    endfor
    return n
```

You stated in your question that the runtime of this loop is O(n), but that's actually not the case. The loop does indeed run at most n times, but that doesn't necessarily guarantee that the amount of work the loop does is O(n). So it would be correct to say that the *number of iterations* is O(n), it's not necessarily correct to say that the *amount of work done* is O(n).

To figure out how much work the loop does, we have to analyze the `isDuplicate` and `remove` functions to see how much work they do. Let's begin with `isDuplicate`:

```
Method: isDuplicate (i)
    for j=1 to n
        if A[j] = A[i]
            return true
        endif
    endfor
    return false
```

(There's a bug in this code, by the way, because `A[j] = A[i]` will always be true when `i = j`. But I'm going to ignore that for now.)

This function's runtime depends on the contents of the array, since that inner loop can run for a variable amount of time. But in the worst case, we can say that since it does O(1) work per loop iteration and there are O(n) total loop iterations, the amount of work done here is O(n).

Similarly, let's look at `remove`:

```
Method: remove (i)
// Removes and performs a left-shift.
    for j=n-1 to i
        A[j] = A[j+1]
    endfor
    n = n - 1
```

There are many different ways we could bound the runtime of this function, but one conservative option would be to say that it takes time O(n), since in the worst case it indeed will touch all array elements at most twice.

Putting this together, we have that

- `isDuplicate` runs in time O(n), and
- `remove` runs in time O(n).

With that in mind, let's jump back to this top function:

```
Method(main)
    for i=1 to n 
        if isDuplicate (i)
            remove (i)
        endif
    endfor
    return n
```

This loop runs at most O(n) times. (I say "at most" because there's a slight complication here in that `n` can change each time you call `remove`, but for now, let's ignore that.) Each iteration of the loop does O(n) total work, since each call to `isDuplicate` takes time O(n) and each call to `remove` does O(n) work. (We add, rather than multiply, these runtimes because the cost of doing one thing and then, afterward, another is given by the sum of the two runtimes.)

We're therefore left with O(n) loop iterations times O(n) work per iteration, for a total runtime of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** work in the worst case.

It's a good exercise to convince yourself that this algorithm *always* does Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) work, both in the best case and in the worst case.